# connect to database with JSP

Tags: mysql, jsp

please i want connect to my database, i have added mysql connector to eclipse but i can't connect to my base help me please Thanks

```
    <% try {
String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/grp_asso";
Connection connection = null; 
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL,"root","");
if(!connection.isClosed())
     out.println("Successfully connected");
connection.close();}catch(Exception ex){
out.println("Unable to connect to database");} %>
```

Comment: You shouldn't do it this way. At the very least make a class to do all this and call the class (to avoid messy connection code in each JSP). Better yet do all db operations in Servlets not JSP.  In any case, `.newInstance();` not needed, and you might not need to specify port.  Other than that, good luck as the problem could be almost anything.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a java class I wrote to connect to a database.  You need to add the database to your servlet container XML configuration files - probably WEB-INF/web.xml and META-INF/context.xml if you're using Tomcat (which is what JBoss, Glassfish and Spring all use, in case you're using any of those.)

```
package your_package;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class ConnectionPool {
    private Connection connection = null;
    private javax.sql.DataSource dataSource = null;
    private javax.naming.Context envContext  = null;
    private javax.naming.Context initContext = null;        
    private String envContextDataSource = "jdbc/DataSourceName";
    private String envConextLookup = "java:/comp/env";

    public ConnectionPool() {
        super();
    }

    private void lookupDataSource() throws NamingException {
            this.initContext = new javax.naming.InitialContext();
            this.envContext  = (javax.naming.Context)this.initContext.lookup(this.envConextLookup);
            this.dataSource = (javax.sql.DataSource)this.envContext.lookup(this.envContextDataSource);
    }

    public void openConnection() throws SQLException, NamingException {

            if (this.dataSource == null) { lookupDataSource(); }
            this.connection = dataSource.getConnection();
    }

    public void closeConnection() {
        try {
            if (this.connection != null) {
                this.connection.close();
                this.connection = null;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            this.connection = null;
        }

    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }
    public void setConnection(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }
    public javax.sql.DataSource getDataSource() {
        return this.dataSource;
    }
    public void setDataSource(javax.sql.DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }
    public javax.naming.Context getEnvContext() {
        return this.envContext;
    }
    public void setEnvContext(javax.naming.Context envContext) {
        this.envContext = envContext;
    }
    public javax.naming.Context getInitContext() {
        return this.initContext;
    }
    public void setInitContext(javax.naming.Context initContext) {
        this.initContext = initContext;
    }
    public String getEnvContextDataSource() {
        return envContextDataSource;
    }
    public void setEnvContextDataSource(String envContextDataSource) {
        this.envContextDataSource = envContextDataSource;
    }
    public String getEnvConextLookup() {
        return envConextLookup;
    }
    public void setEnvConextLookup(String envConextLookup) {
        this.envConextLookup = envConextLookup;
    }
}
```

In WEB-INF/web.xml you will need to reference the data source:

```
 <resource-ref>
    <description>DataSourceName</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/DataSourceName</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

In META-INF/context.xml you will need to link the data source to the database.

Change the "name", "username", "password", and "url" tags to the correct values for your configuration - I have provided sample values.  If you're just testing it is likely the username is root and the password is blank.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/DataSourceName" 
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
              username="username" 
              password="password"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name?autoReconnect=true"
              validationQuery="select 1"
              maxActive="1000" 
              maxIdle="10"/>
</Context>
```